# How to interpret Workbox v5 documentation if not using a bundler

Tags: workbox

I am in the process of upgrading from v3 to v5 of workbox. I am not using a bundler as my SPA is built using Blazor. I am using a service worker coded in straight javascript, using the workbox javascript file imported from Google CDN, and I am not using a bundler.

Is there a way I can "translate" the current v5 workbox docs if not using a bundler, and modules?

For example, what would be the plain javascript way of writing this following code, using a importScripts from Google CDN:

```
import {registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing';
import {CacheFirst, StaleWhileRevalidate} from 'workbox-strategies';
import {CacheableResponsePlugin} from 'workbox-cacheable-response';
import {ExpirationPlugin} from 'workbox-expiration';

// Cache the Google Fonts stylesheets with a stale-while-revalidate strategy.
registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.origin === 'https://fonts.googleapis.com',
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'google-fonts-stylesheets',
  })
);

// Cache the underlying font files with a cache-first strategy for 1 year.
registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.origin === 'https://fonts.gstatic.com',
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'google-fonts-webfonts',
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [0, 200],
      }),
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
        maxEntries: 30,
      }),
    ],
  })
);
```

I am especially having trouble converting this piece of older code:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.(?:png|svg|js|css|html|woff|eot|otf|ttf|ico|dll|json|wasm|dat|pdb)$/,
    new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'dplan-cache',
        plugins: [
            new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
                maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 //7 days
            })
        ]
    })
);
```

I am getting an exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: workbox.expiration.Plugin is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

I think https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers#moving_from_importscripts_to_module_imports is the best guide for translating between the two ways of importing Workbox.

The version-specific upgrade guides are also going to help; in particular, what I think you're running into is a change from [v4 to v5](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v4) related to the [plugin classes](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v4#plugin_classes_renamed).

Using `workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin` should work.